# plugins to lengthen short urls for security purposes

Tags: web-browser

Came across [this question](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/should-we-ban-the-use-of-url-shorteners-on-this-site)

What browser plugins can help us to see the actual destination of such shortened URLs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I prefer a different Firefox add-on called RequestPolicy. It's a much more general purpose security tool in that it enables you to control all requests to external URLs. Along the way it converts shortened URLs to the real URL and let's you decide if you want to go there.

It exposes all the external links of a web page and let's you decide which to allow.

At first you might find RequestPolicy annoying because many sites won't function as you would expect until you allow external links. Now that I am used to it, I like it a lot.

Comment: Hadn't seen it before. I like it!

Comment: Yes, but make sure you use the latest beta version.  There is a security hole detailed here: https://grepular.com/Bypassing_RequestPolicy_Using_Protocol_Relative_URLs

Comment: I am a fan of Chrome, so is there a bookmarklet for this?

Comment: I asked the wrong question. I should have asked if there is a plugin for this in Chrome. This one is more of a general purpose security tool which I think its better than just LongURL. So i will mark this as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use [LongURL](http://www.longurlplease.com/)

If you are using Firefox, install the add-on for this.

For other browsers, copy the bookmarket and put it in your bookmark bar.

One thing to note, if you are surfing a https page, the LongURL would not work as the page would be encrypted.

Copy paste the shortened url into a textbox in a http page and use the LongURL there.